# How can I bring back dragons?

Tags: magic, dragons

So in a world where dragons are long extinct (they're not technically, but the normal people don't know that) , the power creating them or the people who hold that power are long extinct too, how can I bring them back, like logically?
I'm not gonna pull a [Daenerys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daenerys_Targaryen).

Comment: *I'm not gonna pull a Daenerys.* This is meaningless to a many, many people, including me.

Comment: can they do cloning? like do they have the dragon parts like bone, blood, teeth or is there close relative species, ancestor, or familia, etc stuff like that to the dragon to be able to crossbreed or gene engineering it until they get closely resembling dragon ?

Comment: _the power creating them or the people who hold that power_ -- So we're not talking about a naturally occurring organism that evolved on your world. In accordance with the [tag:magic] tag, you should define how magic functions in your world. Without that specification, this question may not be feasibly answerable.

Comment: You have two questions. How would magic for creating dragond works. And second: how to figure out that magic in your world.

Comment: Flagging celebrity status and stagnant careers. Don Henley said he'd never get back together with the Eagles... but the money brought him back to a worldwide concert tour. If the dragons feel like they're not getting the respect and money they deserve, they'll come back. Supposing the public even gives a crap about washed-up has-been monsters from their parents' era. Or even a tax debt crisis... the IRS comes in for all of that big pile of gold, plus penalties. That'd spur renewed interest in coming out of retirement.

Comment: Are you asking about building their population back from "brink of extinction" levels? Or just introducing them in a story when people *thought* they were extinct? Because I don't see (note [L.Dutch's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/171939/43697)) that you need to do anything special for the latter... and answers to that are going to be pretty opinion-based.

Comment: This needs a lot more information.  What are your story goals?  What are you dragons like?  What are these 'powers' like?  Is there magic?  Advanced technology?  Both?  Neither?  A god creating new dragons is very different from a group of scientists introducing a dragon breed program...

Answer (score 4):

For a long time the link between land animals and fishes was thought to be extinct.

Until one day in 1938 a westerner found in a fish market in Africa a specimen of [coelacanth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latimeria)

> They follow the oldest known living lineage of Sarcopterygii (lobe-finned fish and tetrapods), which means they are more closely related to lungfish, reptiles and mammals than to the common ray-finned fishes.

This is just an example, but for many species we don't know about their existence until we stumble onto them. If they live in remote areas and dwell around overnight, they can go unnoticed for very long time. Until someone happens to meet them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will work for you or not, but it's too weird of a coincidence that I literally *just* (two days ago) had a dream about exactly this to not share...

The key is that you mentioned "they're not technically [extinct], but the normal people don't know that". (BTW, reminds me of the dragon in [Monster Hunter: Legion](https://larry-correia.fandom.com/wiki/Monster_Hunter_Legion)).

In the dream, this was the opposite way around; people knew about dragons, but *didn't* know they were nearly extinct, but that doesn't matter. Anyway, without rehashing the whole dream, the upshot was that there was one dragon, the "matriarch", that carried a sort of genetic template (i.e. there was some "magic" involved, but dragons almost *have* to be magical, at least if you want them to fly and not be tiny) for dragons that would allow bypassing the usual genetic bottlenecks. However, because of their rarity, finding a mate was already a challenge.

So, basically, this 'magic template' is a thing that exists and can be passed around. Or, maybe it is formed of the spiritual essence of all dragons, and only becomes "tangible" when there are very few dragons left, otherwise it is just spread out among existing dragons and not noticeable. As long as you have *a* male and *a* female, however, the only problem repopulating is genetic diversity, so if you hand-wave that somehow, you're set. (And if you only have two males, or only two females, you can always pull a gender-bender on one of them, a la Jurassic Park.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to find fossil trees.

Some of those will have ambar stones, which is fossilized tree sap.

Some of those stones will have insects in them, which were trapped by the sap while it was still liquid.

Some of those insects will be prehistoric mosquitoes.

Some of those will have drank blood from dragons.

Now all you need is for a crazy multibillionaire to buy estate in Isla Sorna so that he can build Dragon Park. Hire the best necromancers, evokers and genebenders money will buy. The genebenders are key here, because you need to undo the DNA corruption that happens on fossils and keeps Dragon Park from being true because science hates us.

Now get some [Roc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roc_(mythology)) eggs, and implant the dragon DNA in them. You will be hatching f... dragons! Don't forget to summon a motley crew composed of your grandchildren, a couple of paleo-rangers and a chaote to serve as QA for your park before its grand opening. I suggest buying some very expensive [Inn Sewer Ants](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Inn-Sewer-Ants) for the whole enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

You got several option of bringing an extinct creature back.

**Captain America:** They never went extinct, although their numbers were heavily depleted a few managed to "survive" encased in ice.

**Necromancy:** Here we tread the magical path, a powerful necromancer could bring them back as undead dragons (indistinguishable form normal dragons by normies). Or a form of magic that can bring them back completely alive.

**Game Of Thrones:** Dragons are extinct but they left behind eggs, eggs that either take a really really long time to hatch or need special circumstances like (Magical) fire, light from a full moon, bathed in the blood of a virgin or any magical way you can think of.

**Among the stars (Or just some remote island):** Your dragons are able to to fly in to outer space(Or just across a vast ocean), group of them left and after the dragons that stayed died these came back. Or they just hibernate for a long time and seek a remote safe space to hide.

**Summoning:** Your dragons can be summoned in to existence from a different realm but the magic died out...how can the magic return? What is lost can be found, in temples, books or other holding places. It only takes one person to find it and spread it.

**Deus ex machina:** God did it, he was just like "This world could use some dragons" and poof little Timmy got eaten by a dragon because god was bored. But this is really cheap and often frowned upon. (Alternatively the gates of hell could burst open, releasing dragons but also really cheap if you ask me)

**Science!:** The dragons are just cloned form DNA Jurassic park style or humanoid made abominations that resemble dragons. Hell even lifelike robotic dragons could do the trick.